# efficient way of generating convex hull of binarized image

Tags: performance-tuning, regions, image, convexhull

I have a binarized image with 4 disk-like dots.

[image]

I want to find the convex hull of these 4 dots.

The conventional method using `MorphologicalComponents`

```
Image@MorphologicalComponents[img, Method -> "ConvexHull"]
```

does not apply here, since 4 dots are not connected.

What I figure out to do this is very slow. Code is shown below:

```
matrixRotationCounterClockwise[m_] := Reverse@Transpose@m;
matrixRotationClockwise[m_] := Transpose@Reverse@m;
regionPick[data_, region_] := Module[{mf},
  mf = RegionMember[region];
  Pick[data, mf[data[[;; , 1 ;; 2]]]]]

img = Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlkSH.png";
pts = SparseArray[matrixRotationClockwise@ImageData@img][
   "NonzeroPositions"];
region = ConvexHullRegion[pts];
dims = ImageDimensions@img;
allPts = Tuples[Range /@ dims];

onePos = regionPick[allPts, region]; // AbsoluteTiming
Image@matrixRotationCounterClockwise@
  SparseArray[onePos -> ConstantArray[1, Length@onePos], dims]
```

this gives

[image]

But the regionPick process takes as much as 30 seconds which is too much. Is there any efficient way to do this?

**update**

I found `RegionMember` is unfriendly to integer points.  Changing integer coordinates to real ones significantly speeds up.

```
allPts = N@Tuples[Range /@ dims];
onePos = regionPick[allPts, region]; // AbsoluteTiming
Image@matrixRotationCounterClockwise@
  SparseArray[IntegerPart[onePos] -> ConstantArray[1, Length@onePos], dims]
```

Now calculate `onePos` takes 0.6s, but still much slower than kglr's approach.

Comment: how about `ConvexHullMesh @ ImageMesh[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlkSH.png"]]`?

Comment: @kglr Thank you so much for quick reply. How to make result binarized image?

Comment: `Binarize @  Rasterize @   ConvexHullMesh @    ImageMesh @ Import @ "https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlkSH.png"`?

Comment: @kglr Thank you. But the border is not the same as correct one if you check `1-Binarize@Rasterize@ConvexHullMesh@ImageMesh@Import@ "https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlkSH.png"`

Comment: `ColorNegate @ Binarize @  Rasterize @   ConvexHullMesh @    ImageMesh @ Import @ "https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlkSH.png"`?

Comment: alternatively, `ColorNegate @  Binarize @  Graphics @   BoundingRegion[
    ImageMesh@Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlkSH.png", "MinConvexPolygon"]`?

Comment: @kglr Oh, I think I found the correct way `HighlightImage[img, {Opacity[1], White, ConvexHullMesh@ImageMesh@img}]`