# minimal enclosing k-gon of binarized image

Tags: geometry, image, convexhull

Similar to my [previous post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/287669/4742).

I have a binarized image with 4 disk-like dots.

I want to find a minimum quadrilateral enclosing 4 dots as below

[image]

and extract the coordinates of 4 corners(yellow points) of this quadrilateral.

Or if I have three dots. I want to extract corners of enclosing triangles.

[image]

I found this problem is the same as [find the smallest containing convex polygon with a given number of points](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11602259/1911722) which is called minimal enclosing k-gon. It seems that this problem is studied extensively. Is there built-in or just efficient way of doing this in Mathematica?

Comment: May  the "disk like dots"  be approximated by `Circles`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortuantely `RegionMember` and `RegionWithin` don't evaluate for such a complex question.

In my answer I'll show how to find a minimal 4-point-polygon which encloses points `xy` ( all white points)

**select all white points**

```
xy = MeshPrimitives[ImageMesh[img], 0] /. Point -> Identity;
```

**detect surrounding rectangle (initial conditions used be `FindMinimum` later)**

```
{{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}} = CoordinateBoundingBox[xy];
p0 = {{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}, {xmin, ymax}}
```

**function `NB` checks that points `xy` are inside polygon**

```
NB[{{X1_, Y1_ }, {X2_ , Y2_ }, {X3_ , Y3_ }, {X4_ , Y4_ }} ] := 
Join[
Map[ (# - {X1, Y1}) . Cross[{X2, Y2} - {X1, Y1}] >= 0 &, xy],
Map[ (# - {X2, Y2}) . Cross[{X3, Y3} - {X2, Y2}] >= 0 &, xy],
Map[ (# - {X3, Y3}) . Cross[{X4, Y4} - {X3, Y3}] >= 0 &, xy],
Map[ (# - {X4, Y4}) . Cross[{X1, Y1} - {X4, Y4}] >= 0 &, xy] 
]
```

**find minimal polygon `Polygon[pi]`**

```
pi = Table[{x[i], y[i]}, {i, 1, 4}];
mini = FindMinimum[{Area[Polygon[pi]], NB[pi]},MapThread[{#1, #2} &, {Flatten[pi], Flatten[p0]}]]
```

**show result**

```
Graphics[{Red, Point[xy], EdgeForm[Blue], FaceForm[None], Polygon[pi /. mini[[2]]]}]
```

[image]

Modification of `NB` for enclosing triangle  is left to the QP

Hope it helps!

Comment: upvoted for workable solution! But I do not quite understand the `{Area[Polygon[pi]], NB[pi]}` in `FindMinimum`. It seems that `NB[pi]` returns a list of True or False. Why this could be a target function?

Comment: @matheorem `FindMinimum` minimizes the Area of the enclosing polygon `Polygon[pi]`, constraint `NB`  checks for every point `xy` and give true, if point is inside the `Polygon[pi]`

Comment: I understand. Thank you so much!